# How to calculate values fromDynamic adding edittextboxes?

Tags: android, formulas

I am working on Electrical formulas calculation application.I am new at this.In my application i calculate Resistance in serial & Parallel.

I add EditText Boxes Dynamically. When ever i click on add button editTextboxes are add.

Here i want to how to calculate this edittext boxes values?

Any one Please help me.....

Comment: Get string from edittext like editText.getText().toString() and convert it to integer/float and add the values

Answer (score 0):

You can get every value from the EditText using YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_OBJECT.getText().toString().

So let's say you have two resistance R1 and R2, then

**String R1 = edit_text1.getText().toString();**

**Float r1= Float.parseFloat(R1);**

**String R2 = edit_text2.getText().toString();**

**Float r2= Float.parseFloat(R1);**

So now you can use this two values in your calculation of serial & Parallel.

Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
```

Comment: You should add a brief description explaining why this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this same also Textview

> final int N = 10; // total number of Edittext  to add
>
> ```
>   final EditText[] myTextViews = new EditText[N]; // create an empty array;
>
>   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
>       // create a new textview
>       final EditText etTextView = new EditText(this);
>
>       // set some properties of rowTextView or something
>       etTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);
>
>       // add the textview to the linearlayout
>       myLinearLayout.addView(etTextView);
>
>       // save a reference to the textview for later
>       myTextViews[i] = etTextView;
>   }
> ```